# finding a docker-compose file with wordpress and mailhog already working together

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mailhog

I would like to use mailhog during wordpress development. Sadly, I cannot get mailhog to work with the wordpress docker-compose files i have found online. I understand that it is possible to extend a wordpress docker container to work send emails, but as i am not a system administrator this is not a feasible option for me.

Is there a docker-compose thingamajig out there that already has wordpress and mailhog configured to work together?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can define PhpMailer constants in your `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` section in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Here is full working yml example...

```yml
version: '3.9'

services:

  # here is out mysql container
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is out wordpress container
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - ./themes/demo:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/demo:delegated
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      DEVELOPMENT: 1
      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');

        /* Configure mail server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'no-reply@demo.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Demo');
        
        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our mailhog container
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress

# required for mailhog
networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16
```

Then in you local theme `functions.php` you need to get these config extra defined constants and run them in the `phpmailer_init` action...

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/phpmailer_init/

```php
// define the wp_mail_failed callback
function action_wp_mail_failed($wp_error) {
    print_r($wp_error, true);
    exit;
}

// add the action
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);

// configure PHPMailer to send through SMTP
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->Port = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT;
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME;
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD;

});
```

Then all mails sent via wordpress locally can be viewed here...

http://localhost:8025/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! This didn't work for me until I added the mailhog container to the same network as wordpress.

Comment: @Jono nice glad you got it working, this is quite an old answer I did, depending on your current complexity of images, if you are only running these images.. [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/), [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and [mailhog](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog).. in your `docker-compose.yml`, you don't need to define network anywhere in the config.. they will all run on the same default created network (when no network is defined). See example 5 in my [docker examples on github](https://github.com/joshmoto/docker-wordpress-meetup-demo). 